# Sync UNet death across all clients in unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been learning UNet to create a LAN multiplayer game and everything is going really well except the player damage.
The goal here is to sync the death enough that both clients realize the death has happened, and it is supposed to reload the scene, using `NetworkManager.singleton.ServerChangeScene("SampleScene");`
However the death only updates on one client, but a new error has appeared. When I acquire and call one of the methods from my PlayerDamage script, it returns an error saying there is no argument in the method that corresponds to my float amount constructor. Here is the code from my Gun and PlayerDamage script.
Gun:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Gun : NetworkBehaviour {

    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;
    public Camera fpsCam;
    public AudioSource pistol;
    //public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
    //[SerializeField] private ParticleSystem part;
    //public float shotTime = .25f;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
            pistol.Play();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            PlayerDamage target = hit.transform.GetComponent<PlayerDamage>();
            target.takeDamage();
        }
    }
}
```

PlayerDamage:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerDamage : NetworkBehaviour {
    [SyncVar]
    public float health = 50f;

    [ClientRpc]
    public void CmdTakeDamage(float amount)
    {
        Debug.Log("took damage" + amount);
    }

    public void takeDamage(float amount)
    {
        health -= amount;

        CmdTakeDamage(amount);
    }

    public void Die()
    {
        NetworkManager.singleton.ServerChangeScene("SampleScene");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, FerretCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to send a message across all other clients in order for them to be updated on a certain player. In order to do that, you'll need to have some sort of a game event bus that handles the receiving and dispatching of game events throughout the network.

Say if you have three players playing your game and one of them dies, it sends a network message to the host (regardless if it's a server or a player) that a player X died. The host will now send a message to other players Y, and Z, except X that player X died and thus notifying them so that clients Y and Z will be able to kill player X on their side.

Multiplayer games are harder than it looks, and you'll need to design a system where can make every one of the clients synchronize all at the same time before doing any gameplay-related stuff.